# How to run this query without union operator?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this,

```
year,t1,t2,winner
```

I want to find the total appearances in the finals for a team, basically I need to union these two queries

```
select t1 from cups
union
select t2 from cups
```

and then do a `group by`. However, I would like to run this query without using UNION(not a homework) as I believe UNION is not standard SQL. I can't use IN as I will lose the counts. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Union is a standard SQL.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get two rows for each input row, one for t1 and one for t2. UNION is the proper and standard SQL way to do that. I can't even think of another vaguely sensible way to do it, and even those *appear* to scan the table twice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UNION ALL` to include even the duplicates also.
Then count each team.

**Query**

```
select t.team,count(t.team) as `Total Appearances`
from
(
  select team1 as team from tblMatches
  union all
  select team2 as team from tblMatches
)t
group by t.team;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4247c2/1)

Answer (score 0):

> **`UNION` Operator is reserved keyword in SQL**

---

[***About SQL UNION Operator***](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

The `UNION` operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Notice that each `SELECT` statement within the `UNION` must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each `SELECT` statement must be in the same order.

---

***SQL UNION Syntax***

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

---

Same with [Inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
select t1  
FROM cups
INNER JOIN cups2
ON t1.column_name=t2.column_name;
```

---

and **you are finding two different fields in same table**

```
select t1 from cups
union
select t2 from cups
```

so try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM cups
WHERE t1=t2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find the team name and count of how many times that team has reached finals, something like this might be of help :

```
select team, count(1) as appearances from
(   select  t1 as team from cups
        union all
    select t2 as team from cups
) as totalAppearances

group by team
```